# assigning return values in sp

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the code :

```
ALTER PROC sp_get_location 
(
    @partNumber VARCHAR (100),
    @tempVar VARCHAR (100) OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @tempVar = STUFF((SELECT (', ' + location + ' (' + CAST(quantity AS VARCHAR (100)) + ')') FROM dbo.warehouse where part_number LIKE @partNumber FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
END
```

And I call it like this :

```
    DECLARE @tempVar varchar (100)
    EXEC dbo.sp_get_location @partNUmber = 'pn3', @tempVar
    SELECT @tempVar
```

But I keep getting an error like this :

> Msg 119, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Must pass parameter number 2 and
>   subsequent parameters as '@name = value'. After the form '@name =
>   value' has been used, all subsequent parameters must be passed in the
>   form '@name = value'.

I've already searched and tried lots of things posted in the internet but I just can't make the code run. What am I doing wrong?

I am running this in **sql server 2005** anyway

Answer (score 4):

```
DECLARE @tempVar varchar (100)
EXEC dbo.sp_get_location @partNUmber = 'pn3', @tempVar = @tempVar output
SELECT @tempVar
```

Answer (score 2):

just replace the line :

```
EXEC dbo.sp_get_location @partNUmber = 'pn3', @tempVar
```

with :

```
EXEC dbo.sp_get_location @partNUmber = 'pn3', @tempVar = @tempVar OUPUT
```